# How to scope result of nested 'with' query in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to get a query result where I can do:

```
foreach($user->funds as $fund)
{
    dump($fund->name);

    foreach($fund->tags as $tag)
    {
        dump('Tag: '.$tag->name);

        foreach($tag->participations as $participation)
        {
            /* This now all particiations with that tag.
             * However it should be all participations with that tag
             * for the current iteration fund.
             */
            dump('Participation: '.$participation->id.' User: '.$participation->user_id.' Fund: '.$participation->fund_id);         
        }
    }
}
```

This is the query. Can I get the fund_id on the place of the question mark? If I leave that where clause out I get the participations for each fund when iterating over the participations for a given tag.

```
$user = User::where('id', $user_id)
    ->with(['funds' => function($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->->with(['tags' => function($query) use ($user_id) {
                $query->where('participations.user_id', $user_id)
                    ->with(['participations' => function($query) use ($user_id) {
                        $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
                            ->where('fund_id', ?);
                    }]);
            }]);
    }])
    ->first();
```

My Models (with only the relationship attibutes):

- User

  - id
- Fund

  - id
- Tag

  - id
- Participation

  - id
  - fund_id
  - user_id
  - tag_id

List item

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the second parameter with **use()** in callback function

```
$user = User::where('id', $user_id)
->with(['funds' => function($query) use ($user_id, $fund_id) {
    $query->->with(['tags' => function($query) use ($user_id, $fund_id) {
            $query->where('participations.user_id', $user_id)
                ->with(['participations' => function($query) use ($user_id, $fund_id) {
                    $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
                        ->where('fund_id', $fund_id);
                }]);
        }]);
}])
->first();
```

Comment: I don't have $fund_id available as a variable. It's a result of the query part surrounding the inner query for the participations.